# I'm getting Errors in my PhpMyadmin

Tags: 14.04, apt, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

First i installed phpmyadmin using `apt-get install phpmyadmin`

Then i denied to install DBconfig-common, after this i realised that i don't have the password & Username for phpmyadmin.

So i thought to Reconfigure using `dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` but somehow it didn't complete and i got some errors.

Then I deleted all my files using `apt-get remove phpmyadmin`, `apt-get purge phpmyadmin` & `apt-get purge dbconfig-common`

Now i'm getting following error.

Please help!!
[I am getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvfcs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676688/php-mysql-connection-not-working-2002-no-such-file-or-directory) the path of **mysql.sock** maybe corrupted. open php.ini and find this line:

```
mysql.default_socket
```

to

```
mysql.default_socket = /path/to/mysql.sock
```